# install and load uuid-ossp on PostgreSQL

Tags: 12.04, postgresql, uuid

How can I install uuid-ossp extension on PostgreSQL 9.3? Is it using `apt-get install`?

I did `select * from pg_available_extensions;` but I found no extensions that relates to `uuid-ossp`.

Comment: For more details, see this page [*Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12505158/642706) on Stack Overflow and  [my Answer to a similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122624) on the [dba.StackExchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site. I suggest asking such database-specific questions on that dba site rather than on this particular Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the appropriate contrib package, which contains the extensions etc. I don't really know why packagers insist on this split, but they all seem to.

If your 9.3 came from Ubuntu's own packages it's `postgresql-contrib`

If your 9.3 came from PGDG (http://apt.postgresql.org/) it's `postgresql-contrib-9.3`.